# How notify the View from the ViewModel to create a runtime control

Tags: wpf

I'm a quite new in WPF...

My application reads data from an external device.
When data is ready I have to add a TabItem to a TabControl and, inside it, create a control which reads its xaml file at runtime (because I have a different layout for each customer).

Which is the best approach to do it?

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: You need to implement DataTemplates and as you say "because I have a different layout for each customer", you would need to implement DataTemplateSelector as well to load customer specific template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhh, don't try something like that. Use `DataTemplates` and a `DataTemplateSelector` instead.

Create a `DataTemplate` for each customer. You should have an VM with a property, which gives the `DataTemplateSelector` the information it needs to decide which `DataTemplate` to load. You can find an example for your specific case [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot @DHN, I go to study the DataTemplates! BTW, if you wanna take a look also at my other question ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747544/how-to-pass-values-to-a-bindeded-method-in-xaml